# Validate non model parameters are expected values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, parameters

I've got a page with several URL parameters that are not model attributes that I use for sorting and filtering. Currently I'm trying to validate them in the controller like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337269/where-to-check-and-validate-non-model-parameters-in-rails) however am having trouble validating that a parameter is in an expected set of values.

```
before_filter :validate_params, :only => :index

def validate_params
  if !params[:type] = 'any' || !params[:type] = 'up' || !params[:type] = 'down'
    params[:type] = 'any'
  end
end
```

In this case the value is always 'any' even if the parameter is 'up' or 'down'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should comapre it using `==` or `!=` and not `=`

`=` is for assignment and `==` and `!=` are for comparison

```
def validate_params
  if params[:type] != 'any' || !params[:type] != 'up' || !params[:type] != 'down'
    params[:type] = 'any'
  end
end
```

OR

```
!['any', 'up', 'down'].include?(params[:type])
```

Comment: and do not use `!` before params. `!some_value` is boolean value not string

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer over the others as it also showed how to reduce the code from what I originally had

Answer (score 0):

well if you think about it if params[:type] == 'up' then it is not params[:type] == 'down' so it will always set to any because you are using ||. try using && instead

```
if !params[:type] == 'any' && !params[:type] == 'up' && !params[:type] == 'down'
```

if you want to set a params[:type] that is different that any, up ordown and also use ==

Answer (score 0):

The condition may look like this,

```
before_filter :validate_params, :only => :index

def validate_params
  if params[:type] != 'any' || params[:type] != 'up' || params[:type] != 'down'
    params[:type] = 'any'
  end
end
```